# What is the difference between CoroutineContext and Job in kotlinx.coroutines?

Tags: kotlin, coroutine, kotlin-coroutines

In `kotlinx.coroutines` library all coroutine builders like `launch`, `async`, etc take `CoroutineContext` parameter but also have an additional `parent` parameter with a type of `Job`. What is the difference between `CoroutineContext` and `Job`?

Answer (score 17):

The `Job` represents a coroutine or some kind of an aggregate task that is being performed. A `Job` is a `CoroutineContext.Element`, which means that it can be stored in the coroutine context. The `CoroutineContext` is a collection of different coroutine context elements, with job being just one such element.

In fact, coroutine context is more like a map, as you can use coroutine element keys to retrieve elements from it. For example, if you have a value `ctx` of type `CoroutineContext`, then you can retrieve the job from it with `ctx[Job]` expression. Further details can be found in the corresponding section of [coroutines design document](https://github.com/Kotlin/KEEP/blob/master/proposals/coroutines.md#coroutine-context) and the [documentation for CoroutineContext](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.coroutines/-coroutine-context/).

When a new coroutine is started, the full context can be specified. If this context contains a job, then the corresponding job becomes a *parent* for the new coroutine.

The `parent` parameter to coroutine builders like `launch` is just a convenience to make parent job specification more explicit. As documentation for `launch` highlights [here](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/launch.html) that the explicitly specified parent job takes precedence over the job that was specified in the context. The actual example on how it can be used is given in [this section](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/blob/cbb602d4e7dcb369095f3a0d3167eb5b7ffa33da/coroutines-guide.md#cancellation-via-explicit-job) of the guide.